# How does <ENTER> work on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, master-pages

I have a webpage with a Master.  The master contains

`search1Button` with `PostBackUrl="~/Search.aspx"`

The child page contains

`search2Button` with `onclick="btnSearch_Click"`

When a user hits `<enter>` `search1Button` will execute.  When nothing is active I can see how `search1Button` can be viewed as the default.  But, when the active textbox is say

`search2TextBox`

Things can be a little confusing when suddenly `search1Button` executes instead of `search2Button`.

A. How does the page decide what executes?
B. Does this have anything to do with `Forms`?  If yes, does having only 1 Form limit my ability to control the situation (I cannot add more forms due to major problems experienced by me and discussed on SO with nested forms)?

Comment: **Bala R.** is right (+1), but if DefaultButton doesn't work you can use JavaScript to capture the `onkeypress` event. DefaultButton is the preferred method, however.

Comment: A more component-oriented approach would be to create an event in the master page and subscribe to it. As for the form issue, tap into the base render method and toggle the visibility of the existing form when needed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`DefaultButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx) attribute of the form.

Comment: I see how this can be used to control the default.  I only have 1 form.  I may be missing something but, how does this answer question B?

Comment: @P.Brian You can specify DefaultButton to have a consistent behavior. If you don't, then the browser sometimes has to guess (there could be multiple submit buttons in a single form) and different browsers can behave differently.

Comment: @Justin Morgan - Ok, I get it now.  So for the time being I will need to add some JS (due to single form limitation).  At least until I can move the project to MVC3 and have full control over the Forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using JavaScript, here is how can you do this..

```
FirstTextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "SetDefaultButton(this,'" + SearchButton1.ClientID + "')");
SecondTextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "SetDefaultButton(this,'" + SearchButton2.ClientID + "')");

function SetDefaultButton(objTextBox,objBtnID)
{
    if(window.event.keyCode==13)
    {
        document.getElementById(objBtnID).focus();
        document.getElementById(objBtnID).click();
    }
}
</script>
```